# How can I use template template parameters in older C++ compilers?

Tags: c++, templates

I have been modifying a class which contains an STL container into a template so that an allocator can be passed in.

This goes as follows:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    struct Bar
    { 
     // stuff
    };

    using Container = std::vector< Bar >;
private:
    Container contents;
};
```

Becomes:

```
template<
  template <typename T> typename ALLOCATOR = std::allocator
  >
class Foo
{
public:
    struct Bar
    { 
     // stuff
    };

    using Allocator = ALLOCATOR<Bar>;

    using Container = std::vector< Bar, Allocator >;
private:
    Container contents;
};
```

This works great on all of the platforms I have to support except one. RHEL7 uses gcc 4.8 by default and use of `typename` in template type parameters seems to have been added by [n4051](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4051.html) in gcc 5 according to [this table](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html).
How can this be done for older compilers?

Also I note this is a C++17 feature. How would these parameters be written in C++14 or earlier?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in fact very simple. Just replace `typename` with `class`. That is, instead of writing this:

```
template<
  template <typename T> typename ALLOCATOR = std::allocator
>
```

write this instead:

```
template<
  template <class T> class ALLOCATOR = std::allocator
>
```

As noted in [n4051](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4051.html), which you quote:

> This difference is artificial and is a common surprise.

> There is no semantic difference between class and typename in a
> template-parameter type-parameter-key