# Convert a class wrapping a container to use template parameters for allocation

Tags: c++, templates, allocator

I have some classes which wrap STL containers

For example:

```
class Foo
{
private:
   class Bar
   {
    // stuff
   };

   using Container = std::vector<Bar>;

   Container contents;
};
```

I now find myself wanting to use custom allocators with `Foo`.
How should I refactor the class without significantly increasing complexity or
breaking encapsulation?

I must support platforms using compilers that do not yet support `c++17`
so I cannot use `std::polymorphic_allocator` (unless I use boost)

This is essentially the same question as:

[Should I pass allocator as a function parameter? (my misunderstanding about allocator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921316/should-i-pass-allocator-as-a-function-parameter-my-misunderstanding-about-allo)

But I found that question unclear.
It gives the answer as use a `template` parameter but using this I struggled to make it work.

---

What I would like to write is something like (pseudo-code not valid C++):

```
template<typename X = std::allocator>
class Foo
{
    class Bar
    {
    };
    using Container = std::vector<Bar, X<Bar> >;

private:
    Container<Allocator> contents;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

An allocator can be given as a [`template template parameter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)

The resulting template should look something like this:

```
template<template <typename T> typename ALLOCATOR  = std::allocator>
class Foo
{
    class Bar
    {
    // stuff
    };

    using Allocator = ALLOCATOR<Bar>;
    using Container = std::vector<Bar, Allocator >;

    Foo(const Allocator& allocator = Allocator{}):
       contents(allocator)
    {
    }
private:
    Container<Allocator> contents;
};
```

You can now use it with std::allocator as:

```
Foo<> asBefore;
```

or with your own allocator as:

```
MyAllocator alloc(params); 
Foo<MyAllocator> foo(alloc);
```

You might be able to wrap your Container class using a trick like the one given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119046/c-template-allocator-for-template-container) so that you don't have to convert the whole class to a template. This would let you keep your encapsulation.
I have not attempted this here.

---

Beware that:

```
Foo<MyAllocator> foo(MyAllocator(params)); //BAD
```

Is a somewhat vexing parse which generally won't work.

Also note that older compilers such as gcc 4.8 on RHEL7 do not allow `typename` for `template template parameters` so you must use `class` instead. See [How can I use templete template parameters in older C++ compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71961395/1569204)

That is:

```
template<template <class T> class ALLOCATOR  = std::allocator>
class Foo
...
```

---

For completeness, if you do have `C++17` or later, another alternative is [polymorphic allocators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator). These potentially add the overhead of a virtual function call to every allocation but this is often less significant than the cost of a `malloc`. In the right circumstances the compiler may be able to eliminate this completely.

See for example [polymorphic_allocator: when and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010544/polymorphic-allocator-when-and-why-should-i-use-it)

In this case your class wouldn't have to be converted into a template which may help with encapsulation.

```
class Foo
{
    class Bar
    {
    // stuff
    };

    using Container = std::pmr::vector<Bar>;

    Foo(const std::polymorphic_allocator& allocator = std::pmr::get_default_resource()):
       contents(allocator)
    {
    }
private:
    Container<Allocator> contents;
};
```

Note that `std::pmr::vector<Bar>` is basically shorthand for `std::vector<Bar, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<Bar> >`;